# Wordpress - Editing the end of every blog post

Tags: wordpress, file, post, blogs

What file do I need to edit in wordpress to change the bottom of every blog post?

So if I wanted to add social media buttons to the bottom of each of these blog posts.

http://angeloesposito.com/view/blog/

Thank you,
Art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually - single.php is the page that renders blog posts. loop.php will be template specific, and wont appear in all templates and Evan's answer doesn't technically answer what you asked.

So anyone searching - single.php in your template folder is the file that renders your single blog post page. to add something after the blog post add it directly after the_content()

Some posts will reference loop.php (including the default template) - in there you'll find the_content()

Answer (score 2):

You can use plugin to do that just search for "wordpress social buttons plugin" in google or you will have to edit more than one file to change the desing of the posts and will have to go to every social network so i guess is better to use a plugin :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response.

Comment: you should only need to change one file to add to the bottom of each post - and you can get nead code from something like addthis

Answer (score 1):

loop.php I think is what you're looking for

Comment: loop.php only appears in some templates - its not in the wordpress hierarchy.